# How to prevent diagonal player movement through walls in Unity3d maze scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, unity3d-editor

I created a scene with a maze in Unity3d. In corners where plates are connected if I go to a diagonal direction (Press up+right, up+left, down+right, down+left) player can pass through walls. If I go (up, down, left, right) everything is ok. So what can I do to solve the possibility of passing walls in the corners, at the junction of plates?

Here is my code of movement

```
    public float speed = 10f;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private Vector3 moveVector;
    void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovementLogic();
    }

    private void MovementLogic()
    {     
        moveVector.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        moveVector.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVector * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
```

I tried to make boxCollider bigger and add another one sphereCollider but it is not solve this properly. I added handler, here is a code:

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Wall") {
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position - moveVector * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

BoxCollider + ShpereCollider + collisionHandler and player cant pass throgh walls but this leads to another bug. Two colliders may work two times but it needs only one.

Comment: Does you player use a non convex mesh collider perchance?  Not sure if the colliders you listed are on the player or on the maze.  Another thing to look at is the scale of the objects.  What is the width of the walls?  What scale are they (not localscale).

Comment: My player is simple Cube. Walls have Box colliders. I made walls from a cube. For example size of wall (x=4, y=3, z =0.5). Player (cube) (x=1, y =1, z =1). So width of walls is 0.5

Comment: Not sure that this will solve this issue, but you should be using `Time.fixedDeltaTime` from within `FixedUpdate` and functions called from there.

Comment: @hijinxbassist no you shouldn't .. within `FixedUpdate` the `Time.deltaTime` basically equals `Time.fixedDeltaTime`. So at best it won't make any difference at all but Unity recommends to stick with `Time.deltaTime` which will yield the correct delta value regardless from within which message method you use it ;)

Comment: You could do a [`SweepTest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.SweepTest.html) which basically is similar to a `Raycast` but tries to move the `Rigigbody` into a certain direction until it collides with something ... then you know that you either don't hit anything or get the maximum distance you can move before hitting a wall

Answer (score 0):

On derHugo's advice to use SweepTest, I rewrote the move code as follows

```
private void MovementLogic()
{       
    moveVector.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    moveVector.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movementDirection = new Vector3(moveVector.x, 0f, moveVector.z).normalized;
    RaycastHit hit;
// Check if obstacle is wall
    if (rb.SweepTest(movementDirection, out hit, speed * Time.deltaTime) && 
hit.collider.CompareTag("Wall") )
    {
      //Collision
    }
    else
    {
        // No collision move player
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVector * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    
}
```